# Could not connect to MongoDB : MEAN : Windows 10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Currently, I am trying to install **MEAN** on my windows 10 through cli (cmd).

I think i have completed all the installation part of MEAN and used **npm** to install all the packages as they were mentioned in tutorial and when I enter **gulp (to run)** it gives me this error :-

```
C:\...\nishant>gulp
Invoking gulp - development
[15:46:19] Using gulpfile ~\node\nishant\gulpfile.js
[15:46:19] Starting 'clean'...
[15:46:19] Finished 'clean' after 8.28 ms
[15:46:19] Starting 'default'...
[15:46:19] Starting 'webpack:build-dev'...
[15:46:19] Starting 'clean'...
[15:46:19] Starting 'less'...
[15:46:19] Starting 'sass'...
[15:46:19] Starting 'csslint'...
[15:46:19] Starting 'env:development'...
[15:46:19] Finished 'env:development' after 43 μs
[15:46:19] Starting 'devServe'...
[15:46:19] Finished 'devServe' after 96 ms
[15:46:19] Starting 'watch'...
[15:46:20] Finished 'watch' after 171 ms
[15:46:20] Finished 'clean' after 687 ms
[15:46:20] Finished 'less' after 692 ms
[15:46:20] Finished 'sass' after 418 ms
[15:46:20] csslint: 0 files lint free
[15:46:20] Finished 'csslint' after 399 ms
[15:46:20] [nodemon] 1.9.2
[15:46:20] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[15:46:20] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[15:46:20] [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
Debugger listening on port 5858
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
**Could not connect to MongoDB. Please ensure mongod is running and restart MEAN app.**
[15:46:27] [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I tried to search for the answer but they were available for linux or mac but not for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MongoDb is not running as a service. If memory serves, you may have to install the service manually. First check if it was installed: Start -> Run -> enter `services.msc` and look for it in the services list. If it's there, make sure it's running. If not, check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ for steps on service installation.

Comment: Yeah, it worked in different way. I just went to that folder where it was installed and executed it on cmd. Btw thanks!